Order arrangement of texts of docx documents in the document.xml
I am trying to extract text from docx files, where I am getting collapsed text from the document like the text present at the bottom or in a random text box is extracted first and then the texts from other places are extracted. After working with this problem, we know that a docx file is a combination of XML files zipped together. Inside the document.xml file I can see the exact texts in the exact order I received in the output. I think this maybe due the value of anchor tag which has a property relativeheight, or could it be something else?
There are frames, text boxes and many more objects present inside these documents, all these documents return texts in incorrect order like texts inside frames, text boxes and other drawing objects are extracted first then the remaining texts.
I tried to manipulate the document.xml file with Apache POI and Aspose.Words, either I get the texts that are not inside these frames, textboxes and more or I am getting the same incorrect output. Why is the document.xml file have the texts in incorrect order meaning it is not in the order that is displayed when the docx file is opened? Is there any priority that the docx files follow to put their texts inside the XML files? Can we manipulate the XML and try to retrieve the texts as it is displayed by MS Word?
SharedPtr<Document> doc = MakeObject<Document>(inputPath);
        auto paragraphs = doc->GetChildNodes(NodeType::Paragraph, true);

        for (int i=0;i<paragraphs->get_Count();i++)
        {
            auto para = System::ExplicitCast<Paragraph>(paragraphs->idx_get(i));
            auto paragraphFormat = para->get_FrameFormat();
            
            // Check if the paragraph has frame properties set
            if (paragraphFormat->get_IsFrame())
            {
                // Access various frame properties
                double width = paragraphFormat->get_Width();
                double height = paragraphFormat->get_Height();
                double horizontalPosition = paragraphFormat->get_HorizontalPosition();
                double verticalPosition = paragraphFormat->get_VerticalPosition();                 
                logFile << L"horizontalPosition " << horizontalPosition << std::endl;
                logFile << L"verticalPosition " << verticalPosition << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                String text = para->GetText();
                logFile << text << std::endl;
            }
        }

In the above script, I used Aspose.Words C++ API to check if the current paragraph is a frame and retrieved their positions and dimensions, if it is not frame then saved those text in an output file. I want to extract every text from a document regardless of the type of element the texts are present inside, from top left to bottom right. How can I do this using Aspose.Words?
I also tried the layoutenumerator and layoutcollector class available in the Aspose.Words, to get their X and Y axes values, sort them and extract the text.
auto layoutCollector = MakeObject<LayoutCollector>(doc);
        auto layoutEnumerator = MakeObject<LayoutEnumerator>(doc);

        
        std::vector<ParagraphInfo> paragraphsInfo;

        
        for (int sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < doc->get_Sections()->get_Count(); ++sectionIndex) {
            auto section = doc->get_Sections()->idx_get(sectionIndex);
            auto body = section->get_Body();
            auto paragraphs = body->get_Paragraphs();

            
            for (int paraIndex = 0; paraIndex < paragraphs->get_Count(); ++paraIndex) {
                auto para = paragraphs->idx_get(paraIndex);

                
                layoutEnumerator->set_Current(layoutCollector->GetEntity(para));

                

                
                paragraphsInfo.push_back({ para,layoutEnumerator->get_Rectangle().get_X(),layoutEnumerator->get_Rectangle().get_Y() });
                
            }
        }

        
        std::sort(paragraphsInfo.begin(), paragraphsInfo.end(), CompareParagraphs);

        
        for (const auto& paragraphInfo : paragraphsInfo) {
            logFile << paragraphInfo.paragraph->GetText() << std::endl;
        }

But the methods get_X() and get_Y() seems to be deprecated from the library. The System::Drawing::RectangleF stores the X,Y axes values and the dimensions of the current rectangle pointed. Are there any other classes available in the Aspose.Words I can use to do the same.

"Can we ... retrieve the texts as it is displayed by MS Word?": Only using a renderer which works exactly as Microsoft Word. Since Microsoft code is closed source, this seems to be possible only using Microsoft Word itself as any reverse engineered code never will work exactly as Microsoft Word. But Aspose claims to be able to do just that. And you paid for is. So...

@AxelRichter I haven't yet bought the whole API, I am performing analysis to buy. I am doing all this to make sure that Aspose.Words can do this and we will be able to solve the issues we face with these kinds of docx documents. So you are saying we will be able to accomplish this using Aspose.Words?

"So you are saying we will be able to accomplish this using Aspose.Words?": No, I doubt that. As said: It is possible only using Microsoft Word itself as any reverse engineered code never will work exactly as Microsoft Word.

Usually, in MS Word document visual order matches the document structure. But it is not a rule, since MS Word documents might contain floating objects like shapes, tables or frames. In such case, it is expected that document nodes hierarchy does not match visual representation of the document in MS Word due to using floating objects. Unfortunately, there is no way to return nodes in visual order using Aspose.Words. You are right, you can try using LayoutCollector and LayoutEnumerator classes to calculate position of nodes in the main document body.
It is not quite clear what you mean by saying that get_X and get_Y are deprecated. They are there and works fine on my side:
#include <drawing/rectangle_f.h>

std::cout << enumeraror->get_Rectangle().get_X();
std::cout << enumeraror->get_Rectangle().get_Y();

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to extract text in visual order, since the logic might be really complicated. For example take a look at the following simple case:

There is a textbox with Square wrapping. In the document model the shape can be anchored anywhere on the page, visually it is in the middle of the page. How should the text to be extracted in this case? If the text from textbox will be extracted in visual order, it will break the logical order of the overall text.

Sorry for my negligence, in the link I have provided as library that page shows Rectangle_F in the deprecated list, when I tried to import the library using #include <Aspose.Words.Cpp/Drawing/Rectangle.h> I saw an error saying could not open source file. It seems I have been using the wrong import statement, Thanks for the help. But still I can't extract text from the frames and text boxes, it just ignored those and extracted every other text. Do you think we can manipulate the document's content and extract it in the way it is visualized in MS Word regardless of the floating objects?

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to extract content in visual order and quite complex logic must be implemented to achieve this. I have updated my answer with a simple example.

You just made so much sense, what I am trying to do is complicated but I am trying to build an application where I can extract text from docx files and use the text output to get useful information. There are a lot of documents that were created using drawing objects and it is difficult to read those documents and extract text. Do you think there might be a possible way to extract text from those documents and I am not considering a complicated case like you explained above, just there are text boxes,frames and drawing objects in an order and I need to extract from those?

The case described above is exactly the case with a simple textbox in the document. The only way, I see, to achieve what you need is to calculate position of the floating content and then implement logic that decides in what order to output text. Aspose.Words provides a functionality to calculate position of nodes on the page using LayoutCollector and LayoutEnumerator.

I have been trying the LayoutCollector and LayoutEnumerator, but they don't seem to work after I get the X and Y-axis values, I sort them based on the Y-axis values, if the Y-axis values are the same then I use X-axis values. For the same structured paragraphs with the same indentations the X and Y axes values returned by get_X() and get_Y() are different. How do those methods calculate the X and Y values? And what kind of unit is it returning? I see many types of units like points, twips, and EMU. Should I implement a better logic? Or is Aspose.Words can't extract text like MS Word?

Coordinates returned by Aspose.Words are in points. Aspose.Words uses the same layout engine as used for building layout for rendering document to PDF or other fixed page formats. The code you have provided above does not actually calculates rectangle of paragraph, since paragraph is not a single entity in the layout model. To calculate rectangle occupied by a paragraph, you should wrap it into the bookmark, then calculate coordinates of bookmark start and end. Then union of the resulting rectangles will give rectangle occupied by the paragraph.

You can find C# code example, which demonstrates the technique, here: https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-copy-a-paragraph-as-an-image/270934/2

Looks like the link you sent is private, I am unable to access it. I am trying to use the Document Explorer tool available in the Gitlab to understand the internal structure of my documents. But I am unable to build it.., Can you provide any other reference which I can use to extract the coordinates of paragraphs and drawing objects in docx files and any other reference to use the Document Explorer tool in Aspose?

Please check the link again. DocumentExplorer is provided for Java and for .NET. I have checked both and there are no problems with building them on my side.

Sorry, the link is accessible now. I am still trying to make the DocumentExplorer work, but I am receiving the same error even after removing the existing repo from my system and cloning it again. And I am using Aspose.Words C++ API, but cloned the C# DocumentExplorer, I will try with Java tool provided.

.NET version is the easiest one to compile. just clone the repo, open Aspose.Words-for-.NET\Examples\DocsExamples\DocsExamples.sln solution, set DocumentExplorer as startup project and build it.
